# PowerPoint persistent default styles for shapes

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

For every PowerPoint I work on, I always have set a new shape's fill, its stroke, and take off its default shadow.  Once I give it my look, I know I can keep this as a default style with `right-click | set as default shape`. (I think should be renamed "set as default *style*".) However, new shapes only take on my style for the current file, not for every new file I create.  Is there a way to have these style settings persist for all new files created?

Comment: Have you tried asking this on a Microsoft support site/forum? I think you might have better luck there than here, with something so specific

Comment: Funny you should ask.  I first looked through their online help and couldn't find anything.  I was wondering if someone had a way to do it here.  Can you recommend an appropriate forum?

Comment: Microsoft Pro Level Support 1-800-936-4900

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a default template. Start Powerpoint and create your default template. It should probably be only a blank slide and the styles you want.

Save it as `Blank` with the extension `.potx` in the following location:

`C:\Users\your-user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates`

This works for me very well. Let me know if it helps you.

Comment: This seems like a fantastic solution but I couldn't get it to work.  I saw my new .potx in Custom Office templates, but the colors I set and the default look for new shapes didn't persist when I closed and relaunched PowerPoint.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you tell me what version of PowerPoint and Windows are you using? Thank you!